# Coloring specific points with a different color in Mathematica

Tags: colors, wolfram-mathematica

The output of the Mathematica  command

```
ListPointPlot3D[
  Join @@ Table[{x, y, 0}, {x, -6, 6, 1}, {y, -6, 6, 1}], 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]
```

is the following image.

[image]

I want to color the points (0,0) and (1,2) with the color red. How do I modify the above command for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A very simple and straightforward way would be:

```
list = Join @@ Table[{x, y, 0}, {x, -6, 6, 1}, {y, -6, 6, 1}];
pts = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}};

ListPointPlot3D[{Complement[list, pts], pts}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]
```

[image]

Of course, I left it without explicitly specifying colors because the next default color is red. However, if you want to specify your own, you can modify it a little more as:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{Complement[list, pts], pts}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Green, #}, {Blue, #}} &@PointSize[0.02]]
```

Answer (score 12):

One could use the `ColorFunction` option to `ListPointPlot3D`:

```
color[0, 0, _] = Red;
color[1, 2, _] = Red;
color[_, _, _] = Blue;

ListPointPlot3D[
  Join @@ Table[{x, y, 0}, {x, -6, 6, 1}, {y, -6, 6, 1}], 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02],
  ColorFunction -> color, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: two points coloured]

It is important to include the `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` option because otherwise the *x*, *y* and *z* co-ordinates passed to the colour function will be normalized into the range *0* to *1*.

`ColorFunction` also allows us to define point colouring using arbitrary computations, for example:

```
color2[x_, y_, _] /; x^2 + y^2 <= 9 = Red;
color2[x_, y_, _] /; Abs[x] == Abs[y] = Green;
color2[_, _, _] = Blue;

ListPointPlot3D[
  Join @@ Table[{x, y, 0}, {x, -6, 6, 1}, {y, -6, 6, 1}], 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02],
  ColorFunction -> color2, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: many points coloured]

Comment: Interesting method.  I like it. +1

Answer (score 6):

yoda shows a fine method.  Sometimes however, it is easier to work directly with graphics primitives.  Here is an example of that, though in this case I would choose yoda's method.

```
Graphics3D[{
  PointSize[0.02],
  Point /@ Join @@ Table[{x, y, 0}, {x, -6, 6, 1}, {y, -6, 6, 1}] /. 
    x : _@{1, 2, 0} | _@{0, 0, 0} :> Style[x, Red]
}]
```