# Colour ListPointPlot3D points by index in Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, point

Is it possible to colour points based on list index value? E.g. suppose I have a set of coordinates

```
l1 := {{20.729858261394142, -11.014787072072988, 20.910738872021085}, {26.754953134772755, 12.795549555413617, 12.35084230079088}, {-26.240583655553486, 14.046344120397391, 4.267648394595125}, {-28.350142916856896, -15.381100510373342, 2.203525286738756}}
```

I then use this Mathematica command

```
ListPointPlot3D[l1, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.025]}]
```

I want to be able to specify the first point as red, the second a green, the third as blue, etc.

I'd rather not use `Show[...]` with multiple `ListPointPlot3D` commands...

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936709/coloring-specific-points-with-a-different-color-in-mathematica), but this colours based on (x, y, z) coordinate values.

Comment: There is http://mathematica.stackexchange.com, please migrate this thread.

Comment: I've no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way:

```
Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.05],
    MapIndexed[ { Blend[{Red, Green, Blue, Yellow},
        (1/Length@l1) First@#2], Point[#]} &, l1]}]
```

In this form you can readily switch `Point` to `Sphere` which looks a bit nicer.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out. We can use, for example,

```
Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.05], Point[l1,
VertexColors -> (Blend[{Red, Green, Blue, Yellow}, #] & /@ Rescale@Range@Length[l1])]}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using ListPointPlot3D, is just to put extra curly brackets for each point,

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{{1, 0.5, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1.5, 1}}},
  PlotStyle -> {
    Directive[{Red, PointSize[0.03]}],
    Directive[{Blue, PointSize[0.04]}], 
    Directive[{Black, PointSize[0.03]}]
    }
]
```

[image]